# How can i use jquery validation framework on a select tag

Tags: jquery

How can i use Jquery validation framework on  a select tab

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/377/

I have tried as

```
<select  id="BsnessType" name="BsnessType" class="span12 valid">
<option value="SELECT">SELECT</option>
<option value="101">Theatre</option>
<option value="102">Restaurant</option>
</select>



$('#mailer').validate({
    focusInvalid: false,
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        email_address: {
            required: true,
        },
        BsnessType: {
            required: true,
        }

    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: 'name required'
        },
        email_address: {
            required: 'email required',
            email: 'email address is not valid'
        },
         BsnessType: {
            required: 'BsnessType is required',

        }

    },
      submitHandler: function(event, validator) {
      if ($("#mailer").valid()) {
        callformsubmit();
        return false;
      }
    }

});
```

please let me know how to do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set empty value for option SELECT. Here is your [fiddle updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/380/). The empty value means that is nothing there and it will trigger *required* validation.

```
<option value="">SELECT</option>
```